# Inmobi banner advertise show only in debug device not in other android device

Tags: android, inmobi

i add inmobi banner advertise in my android application

when i run the application in debug device advertise show

but when other android device the advertise not show..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your app approved by InMobi? If not, please reach out to support@inmobi.com to have them approve the app.

If you are integrating with the SDK, please also make sure you've entered a valid URL at the time of registering your app. If you chose not to enter the url, please go back to your InMobi account and enter the URL

Comment: "Your app has been verified. Please be patient while we review and approve your app "

this message show ...now what to do please suggest

Comment: Please reach out to support@inmobi.com to request for a faster approval. Ideally, it should automatically be approved but if it is on hold, they can help

Answer (score 0):

Please add your Device Publisher ID to your Inmobi account's Diagnostics tool . You can test on all devices you have added to the dashboard until the App is live on Play Store/App Store